# how many ticks are there in a second?

Tags: c++, operating-system, clock, msdn, performancecounter

I'm using [KeQueryPerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/hardware/ff553053%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the number of ticks per second.

I understand this is the **performance counter frequency, in ticks per second**. I don't know how to convert this to a unit of time(let's say seconds, milli-seconds or nano-seconds.. anything) ?

How many ticks constitute a second ? What is the conversion factor ?

```
LARGE_INTEGER freq;
KeQueryPerformanceCounter(&freq);
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. If there are, say, 100 ticks per second, the interval between two ticks is 10 milliseconds (1/100 seconds).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the link:

> **Remarks**
>
> KeQueryPerformanceCounter always returns a 64-bit integer that represents the current value of a monotonically nondecreasing counter. The counter starts incrementing from zero when the computer starts up.
>
> To get the resolution of the timer used to accumulate the current tick count, specify a non-NULL pointer value for the PerformanceFrequency parameter. The frequency value that the routine writes to the location pointed to by this parameter is the number of ticks per second.

Here, it means that `freq` variable will contain ticks per second